# scale_y_discrete in bubble plot: how to change the font of axis labels?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, legend

I am relatively new to R and I am trying to make a bubble plot, exciting!
Most of it is working, except I don't seem to be able to do two things:

1. change the font size of the axis labels
2. change the position of the two legends

Variables ([datasheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4rhQ.png)):

`ycode = 4` categories that I gave numbers `(1-3;7-9;13-15;19-21)` to allow some spacing on the y-axis

I have applied some jittering to this variable to pull the bubbles out of each other

`staging = 15` brain regions that have numbers in the order that I want them to appear on the X-axis
`Group = 4 groups`

This is the code:

```
bub$jitTau <- jitter(as.numeric(factor(bub$ycode)))

gp <- ggplot(data = bub, aes(x = bub$staging, y = bub$ycode, 
                             size = bub$sample_size, color = bub$Group)) + 
    geom_point(data = bub, aes(x = bub$conc_area, y = bub$jitTau, 
                               size = bub$sample_size, color = bub$Group) + 
    theme_classic(base_size = 35))

gp <- gp + scale_size(range = c(5, 35), name = "Sample size") + 
    scale_y_discrete(breaks = c(3, 8, 13, 19), 
                     labels = c("p-tau/abeta", "t-tau/abeta", "p-tau", "t-tau")) + 
    labs(x = "Brain Regions", y = "CSF measures") + 
    scale_x_discrete(breaks = 1:15, labels = c("EC", "Hipp", "PHG", "Amyg", "ITG", 
                                               "Fusiform", "MTG", "STG", "Lat parietal", 
                                               "PCC", "Precuneus", "Frontal", "Striatum",
                                               "Thalamus", "Occipital"), 
                     limits = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15)) + 
    geom_hline(yintercept = c(5, 11, 17, 22), colour = "grey") + 
    scale_colour_manual(name = "Group", breaks = c("All", "HC", "MCI", "AD"), 
                        values = c("#333333", "#006600", "Blue", "Red")) + 
    guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 18))) + 
    theme(axis.title.x = element_text(size = 30), 
          axis.title.y = element_text(size = 20), 
          axis.text = element_text(size = 16)) + 
    theme_classic(base_size = 35)

gp
```

I have tried several things with `theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 18))`, but R does not respond to it. 
I have also tried to change the position of the legend (`legend.position`), but no changes happen.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you include your dataset (using dput()) in your post. We can't test your code without data!

Comment: There are a lot of factors, so not sure if that is working.. but I made a picture of it and here are a few lines:

Comment: Tangential: [the ggplot themer add-in](https://github.com/calligross/ggthemeassist) is kind of nice.

Answer (score 2):

Without data it's impossible to reproduce your exact issue, but it looks like you're on the right track. Your setup should look something like:

```
ggplot(iris, aes(x = Petal.Length, y = Petal.Width, colour = Species)) + 
    geom_point() + 
    theme_classic() +
    theme(text = element_text(size = 15, family = 'Garamond'),
          legend.position = 'bottom',
          legend.direction = 'horizontal')
```

[image: themed plot]

I think what's screwing up your efforts is that you're putting `theme_classic` *after* your specific `theme`. If you have conflicting values, whatever is added last is what gets plotted. For example, if I use the exact code above, but move `theme_classic` to the end, I get

[image: theme_classic plot]